# how to get user name in a view instead of uid

Tags: views

I have a drupal 7 website that uses a view to show the content.  The Content UID shows as a field I can display, but I want to display the username instead.  It says "The user authoring the content. If you need more fields than the uid add the content: author relationship"  , which I don't understand .  Where do I add the content author relationship?
thank you,

Answer (score 8, accepted):

it's in the advanced configuration (click on add relationship):

[image]

search and select the uid field (this applies also for entity references for instance)

[image]

add a new field to the output, select User: name

[image]

select the relationship you created earlier (you can have multiple relationships, e.g. if you have multiple entity references)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

- Clicked on Advanced in the view
- Clicked on Relationships 
  -Clicked on add
- clicked Content:author

  - clicked no relationship 
    -now in fields theauthor shows up as an field I can add.